# ActiveAdmin Rails 3.1 Install Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, inherited-resources, activeadmin

I am trying to use ActiveAdmin with rails 3.1, but I get the following error during `rails generate active_admin:install` I get the following:

```
gems/activeadmin-0.3.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:176:in `eval': uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)
```

This happens with any generate/destroy commands now. I have made sure that I have added the required 3.1 gems (sass-rails and meta_search) per the install instruction on the github wiki. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this too.  Jose Valim released a new version 1.3.0 of the inherited_resources gem, and ActiveAdmin didn't pin the gem to the previous version 1.2.2.  I was able to fix this issue by adding the following line to my gemfile:

gem "inherited_resources", "1.2.2"